# VS 2017 unable to open include file 'jni.h'

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-c++, java-native-interface

I can't find **'jni.h'** in External Dependencies when I change from Debug to Release version of DLL project build solution in VS 2017 even though I have provided JDK/Include and JDK/Include/win32 path in C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.

Note:
Compiler shows jni.h and related header files in external dependencies folder but as soon as I change from debug to release DLL build these header files are missing and results into **cannot open 'jni.h'** [image]

Comment: Not able to get you, can you please clarify a bit in detail?

Comment: Have you checked the difference of your project properties in "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories" between Configuration Debug and Configuration Release ?

Comment: Also should you not only add "JDK/Include/win32" since you compile in x86

Comment: Can't offer an answer, but the question helped me resolve my own jni.h problem!  My additional include directories didn't include win32, just include (which was where jni.h was located)

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I get the same error where it works in Debug but not in Release.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Include Directories that it contains the jni.h path or not. 
If not, then add

```
$(JAVA_HOME)/include;$(JAVA_HOME)/include/win32;
```

at

```
Configuration Properties-->VC++ Directories-->Include Directories
```